# Google Maps SDK iOS min zoom

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

If there any way to set `minZoom = 0.1` or any value less than 1 in Google Maps SDK for iOS? I've tried to search information, but couldn't find any

Comment: You mean user should not able able to zoom less than minimum zoom ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz I had to display whole map in small frame, managed to achieve that using `.transform`

Comment: "had to display whole map in small frame". that's why you wanted to set minimum zoom to 0.1?

Comment: It seems on iPhone the minimum zoom is 2.0, and on iPad it's around 3.0 :-(